# How to use FormRequest to post forms with several same name inputs?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am writing a web crawler with scrapy to deal with forms. The problem is that I have encountered a form with a lot of inputs with the same name. The tags are like these:

```
<input type="text" name="CRN_IN" size="6" maxlength="5" ID="crn_id1" />
<input type="text" name="CRN_IN" size="6" maxlength="5" ID="crn_id2" />
<input type="text" name="CRN_IN" size="6" maxlength="5" ID="crn_id3" />
```

The only thing to distinguesh them is the ID attribute. And I want to fill the one whoes ID='crn_id1' with some number. However as far as I kown scrapy can only fill blanks with the name attribute using formdata from the from_response method.
Could anybody tell me how to use the from_response method to solve my problem. Or is there any other methods to solve(but within scrapy). Thank you very much.

Here is part of the html code from the website.
[Input with same names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLHV9.png)

Answer (score 2):

The `from_response` method is only a helper to populate the input arguments of the specified form you want to request, but it is still a [`FormRequest`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.FormRequest) where you can always override the `formdata` argument to send your own input arguments:

```
yield FormRequest.from_response(
    response=response,
    formdata={
        myinput='myvalue',
    }
)
```

Comment: Hi @eLRuLL, I think I have not made it clear. What I have already known is that the formdata is a key-value dict in which the key is the 'name' attribute of one input and the value is the value. The problem is I encountered a form in which there are a lot of inputs whoes 'name' attributes are the same(Just like I listed in the question) And what I am asking is that is there some way to use formdata with the key being the 'ID' attribute of one input because if I use the 'name' attr all of these inputs naming 'CRN_IN' will be set to some number. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: @NNnOoB to understand and help you with how you should request that form, I'd have to know the exact form you are trying to request. You'll have to share the site you are trying to scrape.

Comment: I am sorry I cannot show the website.. Actually it is our school's course registration website and you have to log in to see it... I want to write this crawler to automatically find the availability of my ideal course and then registrate the corresponding course. I have done the first part -- to get the availability of a specific course, but I am stuck in the latter part. And I do not think it will help whatever I post the website or not because it is a more general problem.. The code I listed in my problem can to some extent represent what my problem is. They have the same 'name'.